# Is there a motivation for coming up with $Z=\frac{1}{2}\pi(h)^2 +\pi(h) + \pi(e)\pi(f)$ which miraculously commutes with $\pi(\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb C))$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\left\{ h=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 
\end{bmatrix},e = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},f = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right\}$ be the canonical basis of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ and consider the linear representation $$\pi:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C) \to \text{End}(V).$$

Let $Z=\frac{1}{2}\pi(h)^2 +\pi(h) + \pi(e)\pi(f)$, with some (very nontrivial) computations (as did for example in the Lemma 1.68 of Lie groups: Beyond an introduction by Knapp), it can be shown that $Z=\frac{1}{2}\pi(h)^2 +\pi(h) + \pi(e)\pi(f)$ commutes with every element in the Lie algebra $\pi(\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb C))$. During the computation, there are quite a few manipulations about the Lie bracket relations between $h,e,f$...

Is there a motivation for one to come up with $Z=\frac{1}{2}\pi(h)^2 +\pi(h) + \pi(e)\pi(f)$, as an element in the center of $\pi(\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ (which looks like a miracle for me)?

Comment: Yes, it is the quadratic Casimir operator, which is known to commute with every element. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790669/proof-that-the-casimir-invariant-of-a-representation-commutes-with-everything).

Comment: For the computation of the Casimir operator for $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130223/casimir-operator-of-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc).

Comment: The miracle of the Casimir is really the miracle of the existence of an interesting $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant bilinear form $\mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \to \mathbb{C}$: given any such nondegenerate invariant bilinear form like this, you can come up with an associated Casimir element by taking dual bases. To me, this looks a lot more motivated than pulling the formula out of a hat and showing it commutes with everything.