# Why find Casimir elements?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Given a semi-simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ the Killing form induces a canonical central element of $U(\mathfrak g)$. This is seen as a very important and useful thing.

> Why is it useful to know what the Casimir element is?

I know one can use the existence of this Casimir element to show Weyl's theorem that representations of semi-simple Lie algebras are semi-simple, but what do I gain by knowing that, for example, the Casimir of $\mathfrak{so}_3$ is $L_1^2+L_2^2+L_3^2$?

Comment: By the way, there are several Casimir operators (and elements), to each representation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790669/proof-that-the-casimir-invariant-of-a-representation-commutes-with-everything). The center of the universal enveloping algebra is important in representation theory and other areas. For the relevance in physics see for example [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63394/definition-of-casimir-operator-and-its-properties). This includes your example.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am aware, but why is it useful to know what this element is? Its clear that the angular momentum operator is useful in physics, but what parts of its use are consequences of it being a Casimir? What do I gain by knowing the Casimir(s) of a given algebra? I'm trying to understand the point of the definition.

Comment: You know then an important invariant for Lie algebra theory. You could also ask "what do I gain by knowing the dimension of a vector space? I am trying to understand the point of the definition". Well, for physics it is quite important to know whether we are in $\Bbb R^2, \Bbb R^3$ or higher. Same for mathematics. How would you answer this? In the same way you can the answer it for the Casimir operators instead of vector space dimension, by using this invariant.

Comment: But the dimension is an integer that characterises many properties of the vector space. I can compare the dimensions of two vector spaces - I can't do this with Casimirs (I could compare the dimensions of the center of $U(\mathfrak g)$). If the question were about the dimension then formulas relating ranks of linear maps to dimensions of image, kernel, domain, codomain would be something I would view as an answer. For Casimirs I'm aware eg that since they are central you can use them to distinguish representations and sub-representations by their spectral properties, but that seems like ..

Comment: The [trace](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223053/why-is-the-trace-of-the-casimir-on-the-irrep-of-a-semisimple-algebra-nonzero) of the Casimir is such a number like the dimension. So you can even apply it like this. So the Casimir acts as a scalar on the highest weight module, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130223/casimir-operator-of-mathfraksl-n-mathbbc). Again this scalar is an invariant number like the dimension.

Comment: Thanks, there are some interesting comments and remarks in those links. I think the understanding that I am slowly gaining  is that since it must act as a scalar on an irrep. you can use it as an invariant of these - and similarly you can use it as a way to detect sub-representations.